# Relational queries in Cloud Code (parse.com)

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

**Table structure:**

**`Collection`**
`name (String)`

**`Image`**
`collection (Pointer<Collection>)`
`url (String)`
`position (Number)`

`Image` class has the column `collection` which is a pointer to the `Collection` class.

`position` is used to sort `Images` within a `Collection`.

---

### What would be the most efficient way in Cloud Code to accomplish the following?

Lets assume I have ~3000 images and 3 collections.

What would be the best way to construct a query that returns an array containing all collections that have *at least* one associated `Image` and show *only* the first 5 images of each collection, sorted by `position`

Associated images for each collection would need to be included in the response and could look vaguely like this:

```
results: [{
  collection: {
    name: 'foo'
  },
  images: [{
    position: 0,
    url: 'test.jpg'
  },
  {
    position: 1,
    url: 'test.gif'
  }]
}, {

  ...

}]
```

All I can think of at the moment is doing two queries, one to get all `Collections` and another to get all `Images` upfront and then filter them, which seems quite backwards, coupled with the fact that Parse is limited to result sets of 1000 at maximum. Do I need to rethink my table structure?

Comment: I have two solutions, but I need a little more information. First, is the position absolute or relative? Does each collection have an item where `position` = 1, or is position unique and you're just looking for the lowest number? Second, is the number of `Collection` objects around 3 total, or 3 per user?

Comment: Thanks Ryan. Firstly, `position` is relative, so each collection will have an item where `position` = 1. Secondly, the number of `Collection` objects are total, not per user, though as you've probably gathered it's just an arbitrary figure, the real number would likely be a little higher than that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can do this in a single call, given your constraints.**

If you have a small number of `Collection` objects and you're using a relative position (each `Collection` has an Image where `position` = 1, 2, etc.), there's no need to overthink the problem. These constraints mean there are relatively few items where 'position' < 6 (or 5, if 0 is your first index position).

Simply make a call on the `Image` class and restrict it to objects where position is less than or equal to 5. Use the `.include()` to return the `Collection` object attached to each `Image` object as part of the return. Then sort the `Image` objects locally in whatever format you see fit.

Remember that Parse limits the number of objects than can be returned to 100, and you can increase that to up to 1000. If you `.include()` for the `Collection` on each `Image`, it means each returned `Image` counts for 2 objects, so you can return up to 500 `Image` objects. Sounds like this is well above your expected needs.

Voilá - one call, all your objects.

```
var Image = Parse.Object.extend("Image");
var query = new Parse.Query(Image);
query.lessThan("number", 6); //Assumes a lowest index of 1; switch to 5 if your lowest index number is 0
query.include("collection");
query.find({
  success: function(results) {
    //Sort the results according to Collection, send to controllers, etc.
    //Each result will have a pulled, valid Collection object ready on its .collection
  },
  error: function(error) {
    alert("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
  }
});
```

**UPDATE**
It is also worth noting that this approach outperforms a 'nested query' approach, both for a small number of collections or at scale (1000s or 10,000s of collections)

Answer (score 1):

With that data structure, you will have multiple (nested) queries, but done in CloudCode it should still be plenty fast when you use proper limits and promises.

Try it in curl here:

```
curl -X POST   -H "X-Parse-Application-Id: 1ClVjWioWtW4uz8Nt7zYiXHkoNYQao6Z1rdXd8Gt"   -H "X-Parse-REST-API-Key: VlYbFT8uhPpsYeRW5ezIn1A8bWa5N9OW9riqs4ji"   -H "Content-Type: application/json"   -d '{}'   https://api.parse.com/1/functions/collectionSummary
```

Cloud Code:

```
var _ = require('underscore');

Parse.Cloud.define("collectionSummary", function(request, response) {
    var collections = [];
    var collectionQuery = new Parse.Query("Collection");
    collectionQuery.find({
        success: function(results) {
            var promises = [];
            _.each(results, function(collection) {
                var name = collection.get("name");
                var imageQuery = new Parse.Query("Image");
                imageQuery.equalTo("collection", collection);
                imageQuery.ascending("position");
                imageQuery.limit(5);
                promises.push(imageQuery.find({
                    success: function(images) {
                        if (images.length > 0) {
                            collections.push({ "collection":collection, "images":images });
                        }
                    },
                    error: function() {
                        response.error("Could not read images.");
                    }
                }));
            });
            Parse.Promise.when(promises).then(function() {
                response.success(collections);
            });
        },
        error: function() {
            response.error("Could not read collections.");
        }
    });
});
```

Output:

```
{
  "result": [
    {
      "collection": {
        "__type": "Object",
        "className": "Collection",
        "createdAt": "2015-05-11T21:52:28.406Z",
        "name": "Apple",
        "objectId": "cpTsJBNc9q",
        "updatedAt": "2015-05-11T21:52:28.406Z"
      },
      "images": [
        {
          "__type": "Object",
          "className": "Image",
          "collection": {
            "__type": "Pointer",
            "className": "Collection",
            "objectId": "cpTsJBNc9q"
          },
          "createdAt": "2015-05-11T22:12:35.152Z",
          "objectId": "0AmtlLrlHT",
          "position": 0,
          "updatedAt": "2015-05-11T22:12:49.463Z",
          "url": "test0"
        },
        {
          "__type": "Object",
          "className": "Image",
          "collection": {
            "__type": "Pointer",
            "className": "Collection",
            "objectId": "cpTsJBNc9q"
          },
          "createdAt": "2015-05-11T22:12:58.185Z",
          "objectId": "WbomPr3hUK",
          "position": 1,
          "updatedAt": "2015-05-11T22:13:05.523Z",
          "url": "test1"
        },
        {
          "__type": "Object",
          "className": "Image",
          "collection": {
            "__type": "Pointer",
            "className": "Collection",
            "objectId": "cpTsJBNc9q"
          },
          "createdAt": "2015-05-11T22:19:02.836Z",
          "objectId": "ASLInM7Hu5",
          "position": 15,
          "updatedAt": "2015-05-11T22:19:08.990Z",
          "url": "test8"
        },
        {
          "__type": "Object",
          "className": "Image",
          "collection": {
            "__type": "Pointer",
            "className": "Collection",
            "objectId": "cpTsJBNc9q"
          },
          "createdAt": "2015-05-11T22:19:14.719Z",
          "objectId": "VkCF98Ts0N",
          "position": 20,
          "updatedAt": "2015-05-11T22:19:20.699Z",
          "url": "test9"
        },
        {
          "__type": "Object",
          "className": "Image",
          "collection": {
            "__type": "Pointer",
            "className": "Collection",
            "objectId": "cpTsJBNc9q"
          },
          "createdAt": "2015-05-11T22:19:27.032Z",
          "objectId": "I2mEG20bfp",
          "position": 40,
          "updatedAt": "2015-05-11T22:19:37.554Z",
          "url": "test10"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "collection": {
        "__type": "Object",
        "className": "Collection",
        "createdAt": "2015-05-11T21:52:35.297Z",
        "name": "Banana",
        "objectId": "zxPfnWlm1T",
        "updatedAt": "2015-05-11T21:52:35.297Z"
      },
      "images": [
        {
          "__type": "Object",
          "className": "Image",
          "collection": {
            "__type": "Pointer",
            "className": "Collection",
            "objectId": "zxPfnWlm1T"
          },
          "createdAt": "2015-05-11T22:16:05.924Z",
          "objectId": "vK9O7b5vR6",
          "position": 0,
          "updatedAt": "2015-05-11T22:16:12.607Z",
          "url": "test2"
        },
        {
          "__type": "Object",
          "className": "Image",
          "collection": {
            "__type": "Pointer",
            "className": "Collection",
            "objectId": "zxPfnWlm1T"
          },
          "createdAt": "2015-05-11T22:16:26.676Z",
          "objectId": "oMEMgwauEi",
          "position": 1,
          "updatedAt": "2015-05-11T22:16:30.750Z",
          "url": "test3"
        },
        {
          "__type": "Object",
          "className": "Image",
          "collection": {
            "__type": "Pointer",
            "className": "Collection",
            "objectId": "zxPfnWlm1T"
          },
          "createdAt": "2015-05-11T22:16:35.378Z",
          "objectId": "0sAbNK1LbN",
          "position": 2,
          "updatedAt": "2015-05-11T22:16:39.475Z",
          "url": "test4"
        },
        {
          "__type": "Object",
          "className": "Image",
          "collection": {
            "__type": "Pointer",
            "className": "Collection",
            "objectId": "zxPfnWlm1T"
          },
          "createdAt": "2015-05-11T22:16:42.984Z",
          "objectId": "QVZJmHQJ6E",
          "position": 3,
          "updatedAt": "2015-05-11T22:16:52.405Z",
          "url": "test5"
        },
        {
          "__type": "Object",
          "className": "Image",
          "collection": {
            "__type": "Pointer",
            "className": "Collection",
            "objectId": "zxPfnWlm1T"
          },
          "createdAt": "2015-05-11T22:16:56.827Z",
          "objectId": "NGS39LCAJL",
          "position": 4,
          "updatedAt": "2015-05-11T22:17:01.401Z",
          "url": "test6"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```